# Finding files in a specific date and then search for a phone number

Tags: php, regex, bash, awk

I'm about half-way through this command. I'm eventually going to implement it in a PHP site so if I could keep it down to one line, that would rock!

Here's what I'm trying to do: find compressed files in a specific date, and then grep for the phone number 1234567890. The command I have so far is:

```
find . -newermt '2014-04-30 08:00:00' -not -newermt '2014-04-30 09:00:00'
```

The results are

```
 ./1006AC1.ACT.gz
 ./1006AC3.ACT.gz
 ./1006AC4.ACT.gz
 ./1006AC0.ACT.gz
 ./1006ABF.ACT.gz
 ./1006AC5.ACT.gz
 ./1006AC2.ACT.gz
```

This is good! But, this is also where I'm stuck. Each one of these files contains tons of records and to search the 7 compressed files I usually just:

```
gunzip -c 1006A* |grep 1234567890
```

But I'm trying to roll those two commands into one. Here's the direction I've been heading:

```
 find . -newermt '2014-04-30 08:00:00' -not -newermt '2014-04-30 09:00:00' |xargs gunzip -c * | grep 1234567890
```

Unfortunately, this and the other variants I've tried either such nothing, or everything. I cannot get it to search only in the 7 files that were output.
Optionally, my other thought (because the goal is to implement it to a PHP site) would be to run my first command, and then try to find the files that match using a regex. In this case: 1006A
Then, I'd encapsulate that in a variable and send the second command similar to:

```
 gunzip -c $compressed |grep 1234567890
```

My difficulty here is taking all 7 files, and outputing only the letters/numbers that are similar in all 7.


Thanks for any help! Jared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `zgrep`:

```
find . -newermt '2014-04-30 08:00:00' -not -newermt '2014-04-30 09:00:00' | xargs zgrep 1234567890
```

`zgrep` is like `grep` but understands compressed files.

#### Additional notes

In your trial command, note the star after `xargs gunzip -c`:

```
find . -newermt '2014-04-30 08:00:00' -not -newermt '2014-04-30 09:00:00' |xargs gunzip -c * | grep 1234567890
```

The shell will expand that star, `*`, to be all the filenames in the current directory.  That is not what you want and is likely why you got unexpected results from the command.